# nested gridview issue asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, datatable

```
 Package_Name      HolidayId Holiday_ID Holiday_Description     Holiday_Date
Package1712200466   8,29,5  1   New Years Day        2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Package1712200466   8,29,5  3   Holi                 2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
Package1712200466   8,29,5  4   Memorial Day          2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
Package1712200466   8,29,5  5   US Independence Day 2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
Package1712200466   8,29,5  29  Independence Day    2013-08-15 00:00:00.000
Package1366323919   5,4,3   1   New Years Day         2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Package1366323919   5,4,3   3   Holi                   2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
Package1366323919   5,4,3   4   Memorial Day            2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
Package1366323919   5,4,3   5   US Independence Day 2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
Package1366323919   5,4,3   29  Independence Day    2013-08-15 00:00:00.000
```

I am building a nested Gridview in the format

```
    Package1712200466   

  Holiday_ID   Holiday_Description     Holiday_Date
       1        New Years Day          2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
       5      US Independence Day   2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
       29     Independence Day  2013-08-15 00:00:00.000

    Package1366323919

    Holiday_ID   Holiday_Description     Holiday_Date
    1   New Years Day               2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
    3   Holi                        2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
    4   Memorial Day - Last Monday  2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
    5   US Independence Day     2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
    29  Independence Day        2013-08-15 00:00:00.000
```

Whole data:

```
SELECT Pac.Package_Name, Pac.HolidayId,Hol.Holiday_ID,Hol.Holiday_Description,Hol.Holiday_Date from tblPackage Pac, tblHoliday Hol  WHERE Hol.Holiday_ID IN ('5','29','1','4','3')
```

I have got the two Package Names by the following query:

```
 string sSql = "SELECT Pac.Package_Name, Pac.HolidayId,Hol.Holiday_ID,Hol.Holiday_Description,Hol.Holiday_Date from tblPackage Pac, tblHoliday Hol  WHERE Hol.Holiday_ID IN (" + data + ")";
        dsPackage = bsl.ExecuteReaderQry(sSql);


        dsPac = dsPackage.Tables[0];

        var distinctValues = dsPac.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => new
                    {
                        Package_Name = row.Field<string>("Package_Name"),

                    })
                    .Distinct();


Package1712200466
Package1366323919
```

How do i get the format of the Gridview as described above

I am trying with the following query inside the `RowDataBound` of the outer Grid

```
 GridView gvHolidayPackages = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvHolidayPackages");
            if (gvHolidayPackages != null)
            {
                Label lblPackageName = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPackageName");

                var results = from myRow in dsPac.AsEnumerable()
                              where myRow.Field<string>("Package_Name").Equals(lblPackageName.Text)
                              select myRow;



                gvHolidayPackages.DataSource = results;
                gvHolidayPackages.DataBind();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=54) article (asp.net 2.0) which shows how to bind nested gridview which helps you to get started.

If it is possible for you to use ListView then go through [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html).

Comment: i know how to implement it please could you see my question and help